# Prove that the operator $S = I − A$ is invertible

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E$ be a Banach space, and let $I$ be the identity operator on $E$. Suppose $A$ is a bounded linear operator mapping $E$ into itself, such that $||A|| < 1$. Define the operator $S = I − A$.

a) Show that $S$ is invertible and $S^{−1} = \sum^∞_{n=0}A^n$.

b) Prove that $||S^{−1}|| ≤ (1 − ||A||)^{−1}$.

Proof:

I am not sure about the SW part below.

a) Given $E$ is a Banach space, we can say  that the space of linear operators on E $E : \mathcal{L}(E)$ is also Banach.

$\|A\|<1$ , therefore $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A^n$ is absolutely convergent.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \|A^n\| \leq \frac{1}{1-\|A\|}=(1-\|A\|)^{-1}$ . Therefore the series is also convergent, some $W\in E$, $W<1$.

Thus $SW=\lim_{n\to \infty}(I-A)\sum_{k=0}^nA^k=\lim_{n\to\infty}(I-A^{n+1})=I$

Also $WS=I$ .

Thus $S^{-1}=W=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A^n$ and $\|S^{-1}\|\leq (1-\|A\|)^{-1}$.

Comment: What makes you uncertain? Your proof is fine.

Comment: For instance about the linear operators on E defining a Banach space themselves

Comment: The answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4246228/815585) might help you